# How to create a list of functions using one function with different arguments?

Tags: python, list, function

I'm trying to build a list of functions [f1(), f2(), ..., fn()] defined by the same function but with different arguments. 
For example, let say f(x,i) and the goal is to define the list [f1(), f2(), ..., fn()] where fi(x) = f(x,i).

I've already tried on Python 3 the code below:

```py
F=[]

for i in range(5):
    f = lambda x:x+i
    F.append(f)
```

or

```py
G=[0]*5
for i in range(5):
    G[i]=lambda x:x+i
```

And then, by printing these built functions with x=0

```py
print([F[i](0) for i in range(5)])
print([G[i](0) for i in range(5)])
```

But I get `[4,4,4,4,4]` instead of `[0,1,2,3,4]`.
From what I understand, the way I'm trying to build the list is wrong because the change of the `i` value impacts all functions previously defined. So, how to avoid it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

def foo(x, y):
    return x + y

funcs = [partial(foo, i) for i in range(10)]
for f in funcs:
    print(f(10))
```